# How to set Security Headers for AWS CloudFront with Lambda@Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have this website `https://some-site.com`, here I have omitted the site for security reasons.

When I try to scan the site using https://observatory.mozilla.org/ it produces the following output

[image]

So, I followed this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/ and implemented a Lambda@Edge function with the code given there. And Added the trigger as well with content-type as `origin-response`

And I deployed the changes to CloudFront. But I still get the same result when I do the scan again.

Is there a better way to do this without lambda or are there any mistakes I am doing?

This is the `nodejs` code I am using to set the headers.

```js
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
  //Get contents of response
  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  const headers = response.headers;

  //Set new headers 
  headers['strict-transport-security'] = [{key: 'Strict-Transport-Security', value: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload'}]; 
  headers['content-security-policy'] = [{key: 'Content-Security-Policy', value: "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'"}]; 
  headers['x-content-type-options'] = [{key: 'X-Content-Type-Options', value: 'nosniff'}]; 
  headers['x-frame-options'] = [{key: 'X-Frame-Options', value: 'DENY'}]; 
  headers['x-xss-protection'] = [{key: 'X-XSS-Protection', value: '1; mode=block'}]; 
  headers['referrer-policy'] = [{key: 'Referrer-Policy', value: 'same-origin'}]; 
    
  //Return modified response
  callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: Not sure if that might be the reason but anyways: Did you check if your Lambda function is invoked properly, e.g. by logging something? Have you cleared the CloudFront distribution cache after deploying your Lambda function? Just to avoid the old origin response is still cached.

Comment: No, it doesn't show that the lambda is invoked for some reason. Is there a way to debug this and how can I clear the cache in CF after deploying?

Comment: For logging/debugging, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudwatch-metrics-logging.html#lambda-cloudwatch-logs For invalidating the cache: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#Invalidation_Requests

Comment: Already enabled the invalidation with `/*` and still I don't see a log group for lambda as lambda is not invoking. Any  help on this?

Comment: Not sure how long you're already waiting but this can take a few moments. And you need to make sure you're looking in the right AWS region. For example, if you are sitting in Europe close to Frankfurt and access your endpoint from there (without VPN or the like), the log group will be created in `eu-central-1` (the closest region to the CloudFront edge location you're accessing) and is called `/aws/lambda/us-east-1...` - that's a bit confusing.